# Proof that this is a a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

My math is really getting rusty, I need some help on the following problem.

Proof that 
$y$ in $R^n$: $y = Xk$, where k in $R^m$, this is subspace of $R^m$

Is this in $R^m$ by default?

Comment: It seems that we are required to show that $$V=\{y \in R^n: y = Xk\quad k \in R^m\}$$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that for a subspace all the following three properties must be satisfied:

$1) \,\vec{0} \in W$

$2)  \,\vec{v}+\vec{w} \in W$

$3) \,\vec{cv}\to c \cdot \vec{v} \ ,c \in \mathbb{R}$

In that case $X$ is a n-by m matrix and it should be not difficult to check the properties for $y\in \mathbb{R^n}$.